# Установить значение переменной всем экземплярам класса через unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Суть проблемы такова: у меня есть скрипт, в котором объявлено множество публичных GameObject-ов. Этот скрипт повешен на 121 объект и перетаскивать в unity одинаковые значения на каждый из них мне... ну... хотелось бы найти альтернативу этому способу. Существует ли какой-то способ установить значения всем этим экземплярам сразу?
Хочу предупредить, что я уже пробовал перетаскивать объекты на сам скрипт в unity и это не работает. Также мне не нравится вариант установить их значения в самом коде.

Примерный код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Button_script : MonoBehaviour
{

     public GameObject a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p;

}
```

Comment: То есть это получается на сцене 121 объект сейчас? Может лучше будет сделать префаб и в отдельном скрипте наспавнить его копии через цикл?

Comment: Да, на сцене 121 объект. Но все эти объекты различные. Можете, пожалуйста поподробнее описать, что вы предлагаете?

Comment: Если различные, то префабми не получится

Answer (score 0):

Я такое делаю в методе старт поиском необходимых объектов:

```
 public GameObject publicField;
 public GameObject publicField1;
 public GameObject publicField2;
 public GameObject[] publicField3;

void Start(){

    // ищет компонент ниже по терархии от текущего объекта
    publicField = GetComponentInChildren<MyComponent>();

    // ищет в сцене объект указанного тип
    publicField1 = Object.FindGameObjectOfType<MyGameObject>();

    // ищет в сцене объект по имени
    publicField2 = GameObject.Find("name of object");

    // ищет в сцене объект по тегу
    publicField3 = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("some tag");

 }
```

Comment: Спасибо может быть я попробую этот способ

Comment: поле `publicField` должно иметь тип `MyComponent` тогда уж

Comment: При поиске по иерархии в данном случае лучше использовать `GetComponentsInChildren<MyComponent>()`, чтобы получить массив всех компонентов (а это видимо то, что автору и нужно).

Comment: @RiotBr3aker я обломался с телефона писать все возможные способы, дополню попозже

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно это сделать префабами.

Создать их можно перетаскиванием из дерева иерархии **в** окно с файлами проекта.

Добавить на сцену и в ссылки перетаскиванием **из** окна с файлами проекта.

А потом менять ссылки в префабе а не в обьекте сцены, тогда все префабы в сцене, созданные из него получат те же ссылки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю за помощь, но на сцене 121 разный объект

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно быстро забить поля данными без запуска проекта, можно воспользоваться чудесным методом OnValidate. Он вызывается только в редакторе, в момент, когда скрипт загружен (добавлен на объект) или поля в нём подвергаются изменению (чуть подробнее здесь: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnValidate.html).

Т.е. можно использовать вышеописанный совет с GetComponentInChildren() в методе OnValidate

```
    void OnValidate()
    {
        publicField = GetComponentInChildren<MyComponent>();
    }
```