# Использование одного и того же массива во всех сценах Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть свой Serializable С# класс *(KeywordToPrefab.cs)*. На его основе, в другом C# скрипте *(Data.cs)* я делаю массив. Этот массив я хочу **использовать во всех своих сценах + заполнить его через интерфейс** самого Unity. Как это сделать?

KeywordToPrefab.cs

```
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class KeywordToPrefab
{
     public string Keyword;
     public GameObject Prefab;
}
```

Data.cs

```
public class Data: MonoBehaviour
{
     public KeywordToPrefab[] KeywordsPrefabs;
}
```

Comment: создайте префаб объекта на котором висит data.cs и используйте его во всех сценах

Comment: окей, спасибо, попробую так и сделать, мне кается это сработает

Comment: это очень похоже на это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/968990/188366

Comment: Да, один в один!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо, вопрос закрыт. Ответ: просто создать префаб с навешеным скриптом и использовать его сущности в сценах. Аналогичный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/968990/188366

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote